# Tkinter-GUI Appending entries to a list- After deleting the widget, its values still appended

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this tkinter GUI, where I am appending the values of entry widgets in one list and similarly entering the values of Option Menu(choices) in another list.
I am facing a problem as when I delete one of my widget, its value should also be deleted in the corresponding list but it doesn't do so. Its values is still there in the list.
for deleting- I am using following code

```
self.number_row=self.number_row-1
oneList=list(self.listFrame.grid_slaves(row=int(self.number_row)))
for l in OneList:
    l.grid_remove()
```

and for appending-

```
self.entry_domain=Entry(self.listFrame)
self.entry_domain.grid(column=3,row=int(self.number_row),columnspan=2,sticky="EW")
self.entries_domain.append(self.entry_domain)
```

I thinking I am doing wrong in deleting the widgets

Comment: First, you're not actually deleting widgets, you're just removing them from the geometry management system. Second, I don't see anything in your code that looks like even an attempt at removing anything from a `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `grid_remove()`, you aren't deleting the widget. All you're doing is removing it from the screen. The object still exists, which is why you can still call the `get` method on it.

The proper way to destroy the widget is to call the `destroy()` method. However, this still won't remove it from the list. You will have to explicitly delete the object with `del` (*after* calling `destroy()`), or explicitly removing it from the list.